# having trouble reading or writing json in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

I'm sending a string via .ajax from a .js file to a .py file. I end up with an empty json object.

**.js**

```
var articleUrl = JSON.stringify(request);
console.log(articleUrl);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
    data:{articleUrl: articleUrl},
    success: function myFunction(data) {
    console.log("just sent the url to buttoncolor");
    }
```

**.js console**

(This is the correct string)

```
console.log(articleUrl): {"url":"https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Finterc.pt%2F2YOBCaS%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0CWvO0cAJOtnidnLYVuOLS1MipypOvSzscOH5i_04ZVsg6Fi49zxbz2M0&h=AT2QuFdHIL4e48CL6qV5oV8N-94ZoUeWyaMK4uSfnUBMSahMYC2cdf4yLripNlRrT_D2Qgcy9JuuV3FEBm_scXPHsz9U50UUy2ESngmKwHvqRYcRs3obkUGXLzWmbAiDveN4CU4f7usi47HqRd4PtPDlfJH-St6kbVna4mlifIA"}
```

**application.py**

```
@application.route('/buttoncolor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def buttoncolor():
    import json
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['articleUrl']:
            flash('Please enter the url field', 'error')
        else:
            rurl_length = len(rurl)
            print("rurl_length:", rurl_length)
            print(rurl)
```

**.py console**

```
print(rurl): {}
print("rurl_length:", rurl_length): rurl_length: 2
```

I've tried adding various things to the python decode the json, but all recieved error messages (KeyError: 'articleUrl'):

```
        y = json.loads(rurl)
        print(y["articleUrl"])

        decoded_hand = json.loads(rurl)
        print("decoded_hand", decoded_hand)

        json_data = """ {
            "articleUrl": "articleUrl"
            }
        }"""
        my_dict = json.loads(json_data)
        print("list values: %s" % my_dict["list"])
```

Comment: can you print `y` alone?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just send the URL in the AJAX request? i.e. Don't stringify, just send request.url as a string

Comment: When I print y alone, I get {}

Comment: When I don't stringify JSON first, I don't even get to print(rurl), I get "werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: Is it possible this ajax post could be getting its wires crossed with a different ajax post? I'm getting errors from a .py funtion that uses a different ajax post from the same .js file, even though that function shouldn't even be called.